# Output Cache and Redis?

Tags: php, caching, yii, redis, outputcache

I'm trying to implement the whole page cache in my website. (Just like stackoverflow). I have already implemented the Output Cache, but my friend told me that stackoverflow uses redis as their cache layer and I'm confused about the redis part.

Is redis the same as outputcache? Can I implement outputcache by using redis? (For yii developers, I'm using Yii's outputcache).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii's output cache will store the cached content using the active cache component, which can be CDummyCache/CDbCache/CApcCache/CFileCache/CMemCache, etc(what you set in the config file under the components area).
As it stands right now, there is no official CRedisCache component, but there is this extension: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rediscache/ which might help you.
Also, since Redis is key/value store and a bit more(though you won't use that bit more at all i guess) you can give CMemCache a try(having in mind you have memcache php extension and memcached daemon installed on your server).
L.E: i also found this for you: https://github.com/phpnode/YiiRedis which seems very neat.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your help. i'm using that extension already. So if i set up the setting in my config, my outputcache is already using reddit? (I have set up that extension)

Comment: yes, that is true(`'cache' => array('class' => 'Path.to.YourRedisCacheClass')`). Though, i would use phpnode's extension instead of the other one since it seems it has a more active development cycle.